# Convert postgresql column from character varying to integer

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, psql, alter-column

I'm trying to change a column type from "character varying(15)" to an integer.

If I run "=#SELECT columnX from tableY limit(10);" I get back:

```
columnX 
----------
34.00
12.00
7.75
18.50

4.00
11.25

18.00
16.50
```

If i run "=#\d+ columnX" i get back:

```
     Column     |         Type          |                           Modifiers                           | Storage  | Description 

columnX       | character varying(15) | not null                                                      | extended |
```

I've searched high and low, asked on the postgresql irc channel, but no one could figure out how to change it, I've tried:

```
ALTER TABLE race_horserecord ALTER COLUMN win_odds TYPE integer USING (win_odds::integer);
```

Also:

```
ALTER TABLE tableY ALTER COLUMN columnX TYPE integer USING (trim("columnX")::integer);
```

Every time I get back:

"ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "34.00""

---

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `USING (win_odds::numeric::integer)`.

Note that it will round your fractional values (e.g., `'7.75'::numeric::integer` = `8`).

Comment: Now i get back: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "" So i'm guessing it works for the rows that have data in them, but when it see's a row with an empty string, i get that error?

Comment: @bk201 Run `UPDATE TABLE SET columnX = '0' where columnX = ''` first?